# Filter a TTL file too large for rdflib to parse in-memory otherwise

Tags: linux, grep, sparql, rdflib, sparqlwrapper

I am working on a large ttl file of 20 GB, I try to read in using rdflib but the I am getting a error

```
killed
```

To avoid this, I am trying to create a smaller file from this file using grep command.

---

The sample data is [yagoTransitiveType.ttl](https://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago3.1/yagoTransitiveType.txt); the beginning contains lines that look like the following:

```
@base <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<1908_St._Louis_Browns_season>  rdf:type        <wikicat_St._Louis_Browns_seasons> .
<1908_St._Louis_Browns_season>  rdf:type        <wordnet_abstraction_100002137> .
<A1086_road>    rdf:type        <wikicat_Roads_in_the_United_Kingdom> .
<A1086_road>    rdf:type        <wordnet_artifact_100021939> .
```

I want to keep only the lines in the header at the top, or the ones that contain `wordnet_`.

---

What I've tried so far is:

```bash
grep "wordnet_" yagoTransitiveType.ttl >wordnet_yagoTransitiveType.ttl
```

The problem is that the file don't read the initial prefix like yago: and other, due to which rdflib is not able to parse the ttl file.

```
import rdflib
g = rdflib.Graph()
g.parse('yagoTransitiveType.ttl', format='ttl')
```

How can I fix the issue either by adding 10 lines after running grep command or any other way?

Comment: why can'T you manually add the prefix declaration lines to the file?

Comment: Moreover, a 20GB Turtle file in-memory is probably too much for your machine. That needs lots of RAM. But I don't understand why you're using such a file not into a triple store? What are you doing with the data after loading into rdflib?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to retain either of two types of data:

- Data that doesn't contain `rdf:type`
- Data that contains both `rdf:type` and `wordnet_` (in that order)

---

Less efficiently (as it reads the input file twice), this could look like:

```bash
{
  grep -v rdf:type yagoTransitiveType.ttl
  grep -Ee 'rdf:type.*wordnet' yagoTransitiveType.ttl
} >filtered.ttl
```

...or, trading robustness for efficiency (reading the file twice, but on the first pass reading only the first 10 lines -- but depending on you to provide an accurate count of how many lines to keep):

```bash
keep_count=10
{
  head -n "$keep_count" yagoTransitiveType.ttl
  grep -Ee 'rdf:type.*wordnet' yagoTransitiveType.ttl
} >filtered.ttl
```

Note that in both of the above, we provide the input filename twice so the second tool starts over from the beginning of the file, rather than sharing an input file handle and counting on the first tool to read the cursor at the right place within the file. We'll see alternatives to that later.

---

As a more efficient alternative (reading the input file only once and performing both operations with the same tool):

```bash
awk '
  ! /rdf:type/ { print; next }
  /rdf:type/ && /wordnet_/ { print }
' <yagoTransitiveType.ttl >filtered.ttl
```

`awk` is a full-featured programming language; it thus can perform arbitrary operations, whereas grep does nothing but regex matching against individual lines.

---

If you *really* want to just copy the first 10 lines unfiltered, and then use grep to filter the rest, that could instead look like:

```bash
keep_count=10
{
  for ((i=0; i<keep_count; i++)); do
    IFS= read -r line && printf '%s\n' "$line"
  done
  grep -e wordnet_
} <yagoTransitiveType.ttl >filtered.ttl
```

All of these will work to generate a `filtered.ttl`.

Comment: You don't need to start the 2nd line of your awk script with `/rdf:type/ &&` since that line can only be reached if `!/rdf:type/` from the line above it was false. You could rewrite it as just `awk '/wordnet_/ || !/rdf:type/'` of course.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ grep -E '^@|wordnet_' yagoTransitiveType.ttl
@base <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
<1908_St._Louis_Browns_season>  rdf:type        <wordnet_abstraction_100002137> .
<A1086_road>    rdf:type        <wordnet_artifact_100021939> .
```